# changeable subdomains facebook connect

Tags: facebook, subdomain

The new version of site is not ready yet.Thats why we use a subdomain.To make the link more user friendly we made the links to be like `userName.site.com` or at this point `userName.dev.site.com` instead of `dev.site.com/userName`

**main url**

dev.site.com

**some example urls**

jack.dev.site.com

stefan.dev.site.com

If i try to login in with facebook at this url **dev.site.com** , everything is ok. But when i go to **jack.dev.site.com** im not logged in anymore if i try to loggin, facebook returns an error.Then if i go to **dev.site.com** i'm actually logged.

I try with

```
document.domain = "dev.site.com";
```

with no effect. Any ideas ?

Comment: What domain your session cookies have?

Comment: I think your problem is that the session cookies not being sent to the <name>.dev.site.com because. Try setting you session cookies domain to `.dev.site.com`. The leading `.` will make them work on sub-sub domains.

Comment: But if i'am in jack.dev.com the domain is jack.dev.com

Comment: I try with document.domain = ".dev.site.com"; but no effect

Comment: Oh, also try setting the facebook app's `domain` setting to `site.com`, they validate domains and they should support subdomains if you only enter a <name>.<tld>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14470/discussion-between-complex857-and-marian-petrov)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have 2 versions of your app, one is 'live' and one is 'beta'. Because these two versions reside in different sub-domains, you must create two apps on facebook. That is, the same app can't be hosted on two different subdomains.