# Can I use my authorized facebook app on subdomains of my own site?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-authentication

Many of our users currently use facebook connect to login to our site at www.mysite.com.  We have a related application hosted at "subdomain.mysite.com".  We want existing users to be able to login using facebook connect on the subdomain.  Is there any possible way to do this?

I've found [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672943/changeable-subdomains-facebook-connecthttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672943/changeable-subdomains-facebook-connect) with one answer claiming it is not possible, and we would have to create a 2nd app that the user would have to authorize separately.  I'd like to verify 100% that it is impossible to login from a subdomain before giving up, however.  Are there any workarounds at all?

Comment: Answering the title, **Yes**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By settings you `App domains` settings it's of course possible.

In you app settings on Facebook, you have a field called `App Domains`. In this field, you can add a main domain `example.com` and this will allow every subdomains: `*.example.com`.

Quoting FB:

> Enable auth on domain and subdomain(s) (e.g., "example.com" will enable *.example.com)

Hope this help!

Comment: I missed this thing, and this question and answer save me.. thanks Jonah and Simon :)